# "require is not defined" in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, require, referenceerror

I have installed `vue-star-rating` module with npm. I want import this module in my JS file

```
var StarRating = require('vue-star-rating');
```

When I hover on 'vue-star-rating' shows full path to module and module also exists in noe_modules folder, but when I run my app in console I get a

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

message. I have tried also other methods to import, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import StarRating from 'vue-star-rating'
```

Also, you will need something like Webpack to compile and create the bundle properly. It will not work without a bundler.

Comment: I have tried so many examples on internet, but i couldn't find example same as my problem. All of them have created their own module, but i can't use them in my case. Can you help me

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a compiler to generate a bundle?

You can't reference modules this way as `require` doesn't exist on the client. You need to use something like fuse-box, webpack, etc. to properly handle the require function and include the modules you're referencing in your client bundle.